# Regex or split logic to create array of text between curly braces in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have strings where I need to extract the text between curly braces and assign them to a string array.

An example of one of the strings is:

```
select * from cable where exchange like '%{Enter Exchange:}%' and Type like '%{Enter Type:}%'
```

Based on this example I would want to extract  *Enter Exchange:*  and  *Enter Type:*

*Note: This is an example with just two sets of {}'s.  There could be more or less.*

This is probably pretty simple but I am not very familiar with Regex and I'm have a hard time trying to split the string up.  If there is a link elsewhere to a similar question, I'll be happy to check it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestRegex()
{
    var input = "select * from cable where exchange like " +
                "'%{Enter Exchange:}%' and Type like '%{Enter Type:}%'";

    var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"%\{(.+?)\}%")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
            .ToArray();

    result.Should().HaveCount(2);
    result.Should().Contain("Enter Exchange:");
    result.Should().Contain("Enter Type:");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match the `{word}` pattern

`\{.+?\}`

Comment: you should add `\:` at the end

Comment: So, 

Regex re = new Regex(@"\{.+?\}")  ?